# BIND: zone transfers with views configured not working

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, named-conf, split-dns

We use bind 9.8.2 on RHEL 6 servers. I have setup 2 test DNS servers using views. One is master one is slave. I have 2 views, one for "internal" and one for "external". Everything seems to work except that on my slave server my zone in "view A" is being updated with the data from the master server from "view B". And view B seems to be in sync on both servers. Without updating to 9.9.0 and using TSIG keys how can I make this work properly? Taking a look at this URL it says there is a way but does not go into details on the configuration required.

https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00851/0/Understanding-views-in-BIND-9-by-example.html

"If we don't do anything explicitly to make it happen then both views on Server 2 will be talking to the trusted view on Server 1 because of Server 2's IP address. **While we could use set up additional IPs for this"**

Would I need additional IP's on both servers, or just the slave?

This seems like my exact issue. Can anyone help me with the config on setting up this additional IP and how to "point" it to view A in the named config?

Comment: Use TSIG to separate the zones, deny slaves without keys.

Answer (score 0):

Split zones with tsig keys.

```
view ViewA {
allow-transfer { key viewA-tsig; }
...
};

view ViewB {
allow-transfer { key viewB-tsig; }
...
};
```